# Epsilon in quadruple precision (gcc)

Tags: c++, epsilon, quadruple-precision

According to wikipedia, the layouts of the different precision data types are

- **[single precision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format)**: exponent (e): 8 bits, fraction (f): 23 bits
- **[double precision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format)**: e: 11 bits, f: 52 bits
- **[quadruple precision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadruple-precision_floating-point_format)**: e: 15 bits, f: 112 bits.

I wrote a small program to output the numerical limits for **float**, **double** and **long double** in C++ (compiled with g++)

```
#include<iostream>
#include<limits>
#include<string>

template<typename T>
void print(std::string name) {
    std::cout << name << " (" << sizeof(T) * 8 << "): " << std::numeric_limits<T>::epsilon() << "\t"  <<  std::numeric_limits<T>::min() << "\t" <<  std::numeric_limits<T>::max() << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    std::cout.precision(5);
    print<float>("float");
    print<double>("double");
    print<long double>("long double");
    return 0;
}
```

which outputs (I have run it on multiple machines with the same result)

```
float (32): 1.1921e-07  1.1755e-38  3.4028e+38
double (64): 2.2204e-16 2.2251e-308 1.7977e+308
long double (128): 1.0842e-19   3.3621e-4932    1.1897e+4932
```

The upper limits coincide with 2^(2^(e-1))  and for **float** and **double**, epsilon coincides with 2^(-f). For **long double**, however epsilon should be roughly 1.9259e-34 by that logic.

Does anyone know, why it isn't?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`long double` is not guaranteed to be implemented as IEEE-745 quadruple precision. [C++ reference reads](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types#Floating_point_types):

> `long double` - extended precision floating point type. Does not necessarily map to types mandated by IEEE-754. Usually 80-bit x87 floating point type on x86 and x86-64 architectures.

If `long double` is implemented as [80-bits x86 extended precision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_precision#x86_extended_precision_format), then epsilon is `2-63 = 1.0842e-19`. This is the value you get as the output.

Some compilers [support](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Floating-Types.html) `__float128` type that has quadruple precision. In GCC `long double` becomes an alias for `__float128` if `-mlong-double-128` command line option is used, and on x86_64 targets `__float128` is [guaranteed](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.3/changes.html#targets) to be IEEE quadruple precision type (implemented in software).

`std::numeric_limits` is not specialized for `__float128`. To get the value of epsilon the following trick can be used (assuming a little-endian machine):

```
__float128 f1 = 1, f2 = 1;      // 1.q       -> ...00000000
std::uint8_t u = 1;
std::memcpy(&f2, &u, 1);        // 1.q + eps -> ...00000001
std::cout << double(f2 - f1);   // Output: 1.9259e-34
```

With GCC you can use [libquadmath](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libquadmath/):

```
#include <quadmath.h>
...

std::cout << (double)FLT128_EPSILON;
```

to get the same output.

Comment: Thanks! I guess I was irritated by the fact that the long double takes up 128 bits.

Comment: Your sentence about x86_64 GCC guarantee seems either vague or incorrect. In particular, if you mean that `long double` is guaranteed to be IEEE `binary128` on x86_64 by default, then it's wrong. There's no hardware support for `binary128` on x86_64, so it can't be a default builtin type on GCC.

Comment: @Ruslan, I neither mean that `__float128` has hardware support, nor that `long double` is the same as `__float128` by default. GCC documentation reads: "Support for __float128 (TFmode) IEEE quad type ... is available via the soft-fp library on x86_64 targets.". I edited the answer to clarify it.

Comment: I've been puzzled just as much as @Ruslan: What does *'it'* refer to? To the last subject occurring  before. Unfortunately, that has been *'long double'* (*'[...] becomes an alias [...]'*). Hope you don't mind me having fixed ;)